# SQL - Getting trouble with SUM & AVG query with join table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table, One is rating & second is `property_listing` and I am tring to SUM & AVG based on this fields `safety, entertainment, parking, public_transportation, community_centers` and I have create this SQL query:

```
SELECT property_listing.*, coalesce( avg( rating.safety + rating.entertainment + rating.parking + rating.public_transportation + rating.community_centers )/5 , 0 ) AS rate
FROM property_listing
JOIN rating ON property_listing.property_id = rating.property_id
ORDER BY property_listing.property_id DESC
```

but after runing this SQL I am getting only one row. Why I am not getting other records with AVG?

MY SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2ab0/2

```
[Table 1: rating]

review_id property_id user_id safety entertainment parking public_transportation community_centers
--------- ----------- ------- ------ ------------- ------- --------------------- -----------------
8         553         24      2      4             5       5                     5
9         552         24      3      4             5       5                     5
10        550         24      3      4             5       5                     5
11        523         24      2      4             5       5                     5


[Table 2: property_listing]

property_id title                           user_id property_type_id
----------- ------------------------------- ------- ----------------
523         Bograshov St Tel Aviv Israel IL 48      16
550         Bograshov St Tel Aviv Israel IL 54      13
552         Bograshov St Tel Aviv Israel IL 54      16
553         Bograshov St Tel Aviv Israel IL 48      16

[Wanting this result with AVG]

property_id title                           user_id property_type_id rating
----------- ------------------------------- ------- ---------------- ------
523         Bograshov St Tel Aviv Israel IL 48      16               4.2
550         Bograshov St Tel Aviv Israel IL 54      13               4.4
552         Bograshov St Tel Aviv Israel IL 54      16               4.4
553         Bograshov St Tel Aviv Israel IL 48      16               4.2
```

Answer (score 2):

try with `group by` clause because `avg()` is an aggregate function and you need to group the result by a column:

```
SELECT property_listing.*,
       COALESCE(Avg(rating.safety + rating.entertainment
                    + rating.parking
                    + rating.public_transportation
                    + rating.community_centers) / 5, 0) AS rate
FROM   property_listing
       JOIN rating
         ON property_listing.property_id = rating.property_id
GROUP  BY property_listing.property_id
ORDER  BY property_listing.property_id DESC
```

Comment: are you getting expected result with your actual dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
SELECT property_listing.property_ID
,      property_listing.title
,      property_listing.user_ID
,      property_listing.Property_Type_ID
,      avg( rating.safety + rating.entertainment + rating.parking + rating.public_transportation + rating.community_centers )/5 AS rate
FROM property_listing
JOIN rating ON property_listing.property_id = rating.property_id
group by property_listing.property_ID
,      property_listing.title
,      property_listing.user_ID
,      property_listing.Property_Type_ID
ORDER BY property_listing.property_id DESC
```

I'm not sure why exactly your query didn't work, but in mysql you don't have to specify the groups and I can't say how it evaluates a query like that. It's always better to specify your groups so you know what's really happening.

I removed the coalesce, but you can re-add it if you please.